# Mongo DB BSON Obj size: 1718558820 (0x666F2064) is invalid

Tags: mongodb

I have run into a problem where I have exceeded the allowed BSON size of 16MB and I am getting this error now whenever I try to do something on my collection.
Now my question is, how do I repair and solve the problem?

1. How do I check whether it is an individual document within my collection, or the collection itself exceeding the limit
2. How do I remove the offending document? I just keep getting this error whenever I try doing something with this collection now.

I have already tried db.repairDatabase(), but just keep getting the same error:
"errmsg" : "exception: BSONObj size: 1718558820 (0x666F2064) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: ...: ?type=32",
    "code" : 10334,
    "ok" : 0

Comment: Any idea when/how this happened? You should never have been able to insert a document this large, or update one to be this large. Is this mongod part of a replica set? If so, are the other members affected? It sounds like this is corruption of the data files because such a BSON record should never exist. Have you tried restarting the mongod with --repair?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No idea how that happened at all. I was uploading content to a db, not at all large data sets either. The collection is also not that big, 180,000 documents.

It is not part of a replica set, no, and I tried restarting the database with repair but only got the same error again.

Answer (score -3):

Look at the size. It's obviously not a size, it's four ASCII characters. Go and find your bug.

Comment: The problem is, when I try to look up the document to delete it, it is giving me the error as well. So I am not sure how to fix it, if I cannot query and delete anything in my collection